# Passing selected value of dropdownlist in URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist that opens a new window when I select an item from the list. How can I pass a dropdownlist value to the new window in a URL?

My code looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdd" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" OnChange="javascript:openWindow('add.aspx?ddlAddValue=', 800, 885)">
    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the JavaScript function:

```
function openWindow(url, windowHeight, windowWidth)
{
    var centerHeight = (screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;
    var centerWidth = (screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
    var features = "height=" + windowHeight + ", width=" + windowWidth + ", top=" + centerHeight + ", left=" + centerWidth + ", scrollbars=" + 1;
    var popUp = window.open(url, "", features);
}
```

Comment: Can you pass openWindow(this,'add.... - then you should be able to do function openWindow(sel,url..) and then window.open(url+"?val="+encodeURIComponent(sel.value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply refer to `this.value` to get the value of the underlying select.

```
OnChange="javascript:openWindow('add.aspx?ddlAddValue=' + escape(this.value), 800, 885)"
```

Also, this is easily handled in jQuery, if that's how you roll:

```
$(function(){

  $('select[id$=ddlAdd]').change(function () {

      var addValue = $(this).val();

      if (addValue) { 
          // window opening logic here
      }

      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I like your use of `this.value` directly (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the dropdown object directly into the javascript like this...

```
onchange="openWindow('add.aspx?ddlAddValue=', 800, 885, this)"
```

(Note, you do not need the `javascript:` prefix in an `onchange` command - the browser already knows it's javascript)

And then in your function...

```
function openWindow(url, windowHeight, windowWidth, dd)
{
   url = url + encodeURIComponent(dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value);
   ...
```

Comment: Good alternative here, padding a reference to the ddl +1

Comment: Thanks! Removed the "javascript:" prefix.